# Inconsistent Error ScatteredInterpolant - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a series of coordinates and a data set each point.

```
size(LON) = 720 1
size(LAT) = 1440 1
size(data) = 720 1440
```

when I run `data_F = scatteredInterpolant(LON, LAT, data)`,

I get

```
Error using scatteredInterpolant
Data point coordinates have inconsistent dimension.
```

What gives? I tried `data_F = scatteredInterpolant(LAT, LON, data)` for kicks, and got the samer error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was because my data was a matrix, not a column.

Griddata ended up working. GriddedInterpolant did not because my grid was not regular.